# Does Backdrop-Filter not work on Chrome IOS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently working on a website that requires `backdrop-filter` to use its blur feature. Everything works as intended on:

- Chrome for Windows and MacOS
- Safari for iOS and MacOS

I understand that not all browsers may support `backdrop-filter` which is why I don't mention Firefox.
However, the code doesn't seem to work on Chrome for IOS. For reference, for Chrome IOS, I am running Version 87.0.4280.77.

I've checked "caniuse.com" and it seems like the effect should be supported (https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter for reference).

Here is the brief HTML:

```
<div class="blur">
    <h1>My Resume</h1>
      </div>
          <div class="blur">
    <h2>“Innovation distinguishes between a leader and a follower” ― Steve Jobs</h2>
      </div>
```

and here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.blur::before{
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(0.6);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(0.6);
    width: contain;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    
}
.blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(0.6);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(0.6);
    width: contain;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.3rem;
}
```

**Is there something wrong with my code? Is there an issue with my Chrome? Or does Chrome for IOS not support** `backdrop-filter` **?**

Comment: Try using a percentage for contrast rather than decimals

Comment: @Rojo Wow! That fixed it! Thanks Rojo! How do I mark this as my answer?

Comment: Glad to help; I have posted an actual answer for you to accept

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use percentages instead of decimals for `contrast`

```
.blur::before{
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(60%);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(60%);
    width: contain;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    
}
.blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(60%);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px) contrast(60%);
    width: contain;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.3rem;
}
```

Decimals are not supported for `contrast`