# How Change Background Color & Blur mui5 modal?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm use mui5 modal , modal background is light black  .

[Mui Modal Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vwezws?file=/demo.tsx)

[image]
**I need to change background blur and  white ? I attached needed output below**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To add the blur add this style to the Modal:

```js
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        style={{ backdropFilter: "blur(5px)" }}
      >
```

and for the background color change the Box styles:

```js
const style = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: "background.paper", // Change to whatever color you want
  border: "2px solid #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4
};

...

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        style={{ backdropFilter: "blur(5px)" }}
      >
{/* Apply styles here: */}
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Text in a modal
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
```

For background color outside of modal change the stylings of the Modal:

```js
style={{ backdropFilter: "blur(5px)", 
backgroundColor: "rgb(200, 0, 0, 0.5)" }}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-blur-and-background-color-tyn0vv)

Comment: I got a blur effect ok, not box background color need outside of modal background color is light white see second image

Comment: @somaiyappan im pretty sure the color thats outside the modal is the blur

Comment: `style={{ backdropFilter: "blur(5px)" }}` is not working in iOS. (In Android, it's working well.) Is there any other solution?

Comment: @SatelBill https://stackoverflow.com/a/66605734/17616093

Comment: @Chad, Thank you for your answer. I solved by using below (@Abi Ji's)answer. It worked well in both Android/iOS

Answer (score 2):

Using `sx` prop directly in Modal component :

```
<Modal
  sx={{ 
    "& > .MuiBackdrop-root" : {
            backdropFilter: "blur(2px)"
          }
    }}
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
.
.
/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly in both Android & iOS. Above answers are working in Android only. Thanks, @Abi Ji